# Verilog multiple checks on assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I can't figure out why there is a synthax error in this code:

```
mem_check_msk = (membytes[i] == 3) ? 32'h00ffffff : 
                (membytes[i] == 2) ? (mempa[i][1:0] == 2'b00) ? endianess ? 32'hffff0000 : 32'h0000ffff :       
                (membytes[i] == 1) ? (mempa[i][1:0] == 2'b00) ? endianess ? 32'hff000000 : 32'h000000ff :
                                     (mempa[i][1:0] == 2'b01) ? endianess ? 32'h00ff0000 : 32'h0000ff00 :
                                     (mempa[i][1:0] == 2'b10) ? endianess ? 32'h0000ff00 : 32'h00ff0000 :
                                     (mempa[i][1:0] == 2'b11) ? endianess ? 32'h000000ff : 32'hff000000 : 
                32'hffffffff;
```

Is complaining about the ';' at the end. Just can't figure out where I'm wrong

Comment: I don't understand this syntax either. Why there is two `?` on both sides of `endianess`? The ternary operator syntax is `x ? y : z;` Take a look on how to structurize nested ternary constructs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091314/is-a-bad-practice-to-use-long-nested-if-else-in-assign-statement

Comment: Because there are multiple checks, so first I check the value of mmpa[1:0] then I check if endianess is set or not. Eg: x ? y ? z ? a : b : ...

Comment: I have counted 13 `?` marks in your code and only 11 `:`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. at least we agree on the number of `?` :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. yep, you right. I'll remove my comment

Comment: Yeah there are 13 ? and 11 :  ...got that

Comment: Problem solved, added 2 more ':' values and all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments there were 13 `?` and only 11 `:` Problem rectified.